# My npm version and node versions are incompatible even with nvm

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am new to node and npm. I need to be able to run a program repo for work, and it has  node version 10.13.0 compatibility, even 8.11. I tried installing nvm but now whenever I run ANY npm command (even npm -v) I am getting this error on the cmd:

```
ERROR: npm v9.8.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.13.0.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\\Users\\mateo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\exit-handler.js:19
const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
`your text`at new Script (vm.js:79:7)

at createScript (vm.js:251:10)

at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)

at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)

at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)

at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)

at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Any specific reason that you are using old node version of `10.13`?

Comment: Yes, the repo I am trying to work with is compatible mainly with that version. Whenever I tried with a newer version with NVM I got upstream dependency conflicts. However now I realised even running npm --version is giving me the SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an old version of Node `v10.13.0`, you will have to downgrade your `npm` version `v6.14.12` to the most recent compatible version with your node version

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.12
```

You can check the table of releases here.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases